# QTableWidget functions in a QTabWidget

Tags: c++, qt, containers, qt5.1

How can I select a QTableWidget cell in a QTabWidget tab?

**How I implement:**

`Wbook` and `Ssheet` represent a workbook and spreadsheet. I implement them under `ExcelMockWidget` container class. I can’t figure out how to access my `Ssheet` cells once they have been added to a `Wbook` tab.  I do understand `Ssheet` is cast into a `QWidget` once I insert into my `Wbook`, but would that matter?

Here is my repository for the [ExcelView Example](https://github.com/CCi-BClark/MockExcel).

---

Here is my classes:

ExcelMockWidget:

```
class ExcelMockWidget : public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ExcelMockWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~ExcelMockWidget();
    void addCell(int row, int column, QVariant cell);
    void addSheet(int index, QString title);
    void setSheetProperties(int rows, int columns, QStringList headers);
signals:
    void indexChanged(int);
public slots:
    void emitIndexChange(int index);
    void select(int row, int column);

private:
    Wbook *book;
    Ssheet *sheet;
};

ExcelMockWidget::ExcelMockWidget(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent) {
    book = new Wbook;
    QVBoxLayout *container;
    container = new QVBoxLayout;
    container->addWidget(book);
    setLayout(container);
    connect(book,SIGNAL(changedIndex(int)),this,SLOT(emitIndexChange(int)));
}

ExcelMockWidget::~ExcelMockWidget(){

}

void ExcelMockWidget::addCell(int row, int column, QVariant cell){
    sheet->setCell(row,column,cell);
}

void ExcelMockWidget::addSheet(int index, QString title){
    book->createTab(index, title, sheet);
}

void ExcelMockWidget::setSheetProperties(int rows, int columns, QStringList headers){
    sheet = new Ssheet;
    sheet->setSheetColumnSpan(columns);
    sheet->setSheetRowSpan(rows);
    sheet->setSheetHeaders(headers);
}

void ExcelMockWidget::emitIndexChange(int index){
    emit indexChanged(index);
}

void ExcelMockWidget::select(int row, int column){
    book->selectCell(row, column);
}
```

Wbook:

```
namespace Ui {
class Wbook;
}

class Wbook : public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Wbook(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Wbook();    
    void createTab(int index, QString title, Ssheet *worksheet);
    void selectTab(int tab);
    void selectCell(int row, int column);
signals:
    void changedIndex(int);
public slots:
    void emitIndexChange(int index);

protected:

private:
    Ui::Wbook *ui;
};
Wbook::Wbook(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Wbook){
    ui->setupUi(this);
    connect(ui->tabWidget,SIGNAL(currentChanged(int)),this,SLOT(emitIndexChange(int)));
}

Wbook::~Wbook(){
    delete ui;
}

void Wbook::createTab(int index, QString title, Ssheet *worksheet){
    ui->tabWidget->insertTab(index, worksheet, title);
}

void Wbook::selectTab(int tab){
    // 0 for no selection and 1 -> for created tabs.
    ui->tabWidget->setCurrentIndex(tab);
}

void Wbook::selectCell(int row, int column){
    ui->tabWidget->currentWidget()->childAt(row+1,column+1)->setFocus();
}

void Wbook::emitIndexChange(int index){
    emit changedIndex(index);
}
```

Ssheet:

```
namespace Ui {
class Ssheet;
}

class Ssheet : public QWidget{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Ssheet(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Ssheet();
    void setSheetTitle(QString title);
    void setSheetRowSpan(int n);
    void setSheetColumnSpan(int n);
    void setSheetHeaders(QStringList headers);
    void setCell(int row, int column, QVariant cell);

    void selectRow(int row);
    void selectCell(int row, int column);
private:
    Ui::Ssheet *ui;
};

Ssheet::Ssheet(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent), ui(new Ui::Ssheet){
    ui->setupUi(this);

    ui->table->verticalHeader()->setVisible(false);

    ui->table->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
    ui->table->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectItems);
    ui->table->setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection);
    ui->table->setStyleSheet("QTableWidget {selection-background-color: black; selection-color: white}");

    ui->table->setShowGrid(false);
}

Ssheet::~Ssheet(){
    delete ui;
}

void Ssheet::setSheetTitle(QString title){
    ui->table->setObjectName(title);
}

void Ssheet::setSheetRowSpan(int n){
    ui->table->setRowCount(n);
}

void Ssheet::setSheetColumnSpan(int n){
    ui->table->setColumnCount(n);
}

void Ssheet::setSheetHeaders(QStringList headers){
    ui->table->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headers);
}

void Ssheet::setCell(int row, int column, QVariant cell){
    QTableWidgetItem *input = new QTableWidgetItem;
    input->setData(0,cell);
    ui->table->setItem(row-1,column,input);
}

void Ssheet::selectCell(int row, int column){
    ui->table->setCurrentCell(row,column);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have only one `Ssheet` hardcoded into `ExcelMockWidget` class. Guess you need to create new `Ssheet` on every call to `Wbook::createTab()`. Like this:

```
book->createTab(index, title, new Ssheet(this));
```

Then get proper `Ssheet` widget with `QTabWidget::widget()` when you need it:

```
sheet = static_cast<Ssheet*>(QTabWidget::widget(page));
```

And... access its cells!

Comment: Thank you!  I had to create a function to return the current QWidget of Wbook since I used designer.  Although it would be better practice to probably inherit QTabWidget in this situation.  It has been interesting trying to figure this out.

Comment: Here are my exact changes: [Qt Forums](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/36755/#156970)